# My client doesn't want IOS App in the App store, how to do it?

Tags: ios, app-store, licensing

I have my first client who doesn't whant the App I am developing in the App Store, he wants his clients to have access to the app using like a Ad Hoc distributions (without the 100 devices limitation by Apple)

IS there a way to do it, or I have to stick with App Store and wait for the countless 15 days approval for any new release?

I read about the enterprise but the users are not employees but customers, I believe it doesn't apply

Comment: Then I think you're stuck with the app store.

Comment: Ad-Hoc provisions expire anyway. Yes, the app store is the way here. Many apps are data driven, and they can customize the app simply by downloading new data.

Comment: Try custom B2B: https://developer.apple.com/programs/volume/b2b/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options. Firstly you will need to decide what is the likely, minimum and maximum number of people that will be using the application and how they will need access to it.

Low maximum < 100 users. You can use ad-hoc distribution with 100 devices using a normal apple developer account.

High maximum (Clients don't need to be able to download the app themselves). You can use an [enterprise](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/) account (As you mention could be lightly risky as it may be breaking their terms not 100% sure, would merit some further reading. If you can go through the approval process shouldn't be to hard).

For both these methods you can then distribute the application using a distribution solution such as [Silverback](http://silverbackmdm.com/products/silversync/) or for cheaper options that will require more effort [TestFlight](http://testflightapp.com/) or [HockeyApp](http://hockeyapp.net/features/) (Not their original purpose but will function for what you need)

High maximum (Clients need to be able to download the app themselves). You can use Apples [B2B](https://developer.apple.com/programs/volume/b2b/) solution or if you have an internal sign up process something like Silverback.

Another thing you should look into is showing your customer that a) approvals don't always take 15 days for updates (They initial process of putting it on the app store is longer) and b) you shouldn't be having countless versions being uploaded all the time.

You should also explain that you instantly gain access to new customers that can stumble upon your application generating more business and potential customers are more likely to trust an application from the appstore.

I should also mention although silverback is the only MDM/alternate distribution I have used it is very pricey and I'm sure there are cheaper alternatives.

Just to elaborate on the enterprise license use. Are the customers part of a large organisation? One of the projects I worked on was with a large company that needed to distribute applications to 1000s of employees. We asked them to apply for an enterprise license and make us users on the account allowing us to use ad-hoc distribution with and enterprise license. There was a major draw back from this as their IT support manager whom created the account left after 6 months and didn't hand off his email account which lead to all the profiles on the enterprise account expiring which meant a day of downtime for the application.

Answer (score 1):

The best way for you would be to enroll with [**Volume Purchase Program for Business**](https://developer.apple.com/programs/volume/b2b/).

Once your customer has a volume purchasing account with Apple, they can get custom B2B apps you’ve built for them. Customers can select the app and enter the quantity they want to purchase from the [Volume Purchase Program](http://www.apple.com/business/vpp/) website.

Alternatively you can just use a standard membership with a limit of 100 devices and distribute your app using services like [HockeyApp](http://hockeyapp.net/features/) or [TestFlight](https://testflightapp.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Another rarely mentioned method of iOS app distribution which may be suitable, is if the app's price or it's support cost is high enough that an extra $99/annum isn't a deal breaker.  If so, then each customer or customer business can enroll in the iOS Developer program themselves, and (if necessary) be given a User account on a Mac so that they can generate their own device registrations and Ad Hoc app Distribution certificates.

Then the app can be distributed as source code, as a project containing a pre-build static library containing the app without source, or (as an offered consulting or support service) as an app pre-built and signed by the Developer but using the customer's own Ad Hoc Distribution certificates.